# Break loop on keypress

Tags: python-2.7

I have a continuous loop that modifies data in an array and pauses for one second on every loop. Which is no problem..but I also need to have to print  a specific part of the array to the screen on a specific keypress is entered, without interrupting the continuous loop running in one second intervals.

Any ideas on how to get the keypress while not distrupting the loop?

Comment: I've never done this outside of a windowing system but this post seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175964/python-method-for-reading-keypress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) or [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#module-threading) library in order to spawn a new process/thread that will run the continuos loop, and continue the main flow with reading the user input (print a specific part of the array to the screen etc).

Example:

```
import threading

def loop():
    for i in range(3):
        print "running in a loop"
        sleep(3)
    print "success"

if __name__ == '__main__':

    t = threading.Thread(target=loop)
    t.start()
    user_input = raw_input("Please enter a value:")
    print user_input
    t.join()
```

Comment: This looks like it's along the lines of what I need. Do you have a document that explains this or can you at least explain the target =loop part?

Comment: @StevenLutz `target=loop` means that the thread that'll get spawned will run the function `loop()` when the `start()` function gets called. `join()` means waiting till the thread has done running its task.

Comment: I'm understanding this a bit better now. but I have one last question. take a look at this code:
import threading
import time

def loop():
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        print "This is a Loop"
        time.sleep(1)
    print "success"

if __name__ == '__main__':

    t = threading.Thread(target=loop)
    t.start()
    while True:
        user_input = raw_input("Please enter a value:")
        print "User input: " + user_input
        print "Current count: " + count
    t.join()
How do I get count to be passed outside the thread? I'm getting a count isn't defined err.

Comment: @StevenLutz Please post a *new* question (in case this *is* a new question) or update the current one (in case this is only an update that adds information and doesn't change the original question). Good luck!

Comment: After posting that I realized I should probably start a new question, which I'm doing now.

Comment: @StevenLutz (thumbsup)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the [`select`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#non-blocking-sockets) module. [Here's](http://pymotw.com/2/select/) a tutorial on waiting for I/O.

For the purpose of doing something on keypress, you could use something like:

```
import sys
from select import select

# Main loop
while True:
    # Check if something has been input. If so, exit.
    if sys.stdin in select([sys.stdin, ], [], [], 0)[0]:
        # Absorb the input
        inpt = sys.stdin.readline()
        # Do something...
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't read your question completely. This tells you how to break the loop, but not how to keep the one-second interval. If you do something else, you're not counting down, so you'd probably still need to spawn a new process or something, as another answer suggested. Thought this answer might still be of some value, though.