# A non blocking way to sleep/wait in twisted?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted

Is there a non-blocking way to wait or come back to this function within twisted?

I have a loop ticker that is just set to `tick` on a set interval and that is all working GREAT. However, when stopping it I want to make sure that it isn't currently in a `Tick` doing any work. If it is I just want twisted to come back to it and kill it in a moment.

```
def stop(self):
    import time
    while self.in_tick:
        time.sleep(.001) # Blocking
    self.active = False
    self.reset()
    self.timer.stop()
```

Sometimes this above function gets called while another thread is running a `Tick` operation and I want to finish the `Tick` and then come back and stop this.

I **DO NOT** want to block the loop in anyway during this operation. How could I do so?

Comment: Please explain why you do not want to loop!

Comment: Sorry might have misread that.

Comment: What you can do it to check for your condition at the beginning of the method and if it does not apply, call itself with a `callLater`. https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.1.0/core/howto/time.html

Comment: @KlausD. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: A very similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216749/break-loop-on-keypress) which isn't `twisted`-related, but more general.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit strange to do a time.sleep() instead of just waiting for an event to signal and fire a deferred to do what you want. With threads you might wake up this thread, check 'self.in_tick == False' and before you reach 'self.active = False', the other thread starts the new tick, so this might have a race condition and may not work as you expect anyway. So hopefully you have some other thread synchronization somewhere to make it work.

You can try to split your code into two functions and have one that schedules itself if not done.

```
def stop(self):
    # avoid reentracy
    if not self._stop_call_running:
        self._stop()

def _stop(self):
    if self.in_tick:
       # reschedule itself
       self._stop_call_running = reactor.callLater(0.001, self._stop)
       return
    self.active = False
    self.reset()
    self.timer.stop()
    self._stop_call_running = None
```

You might also look at `twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall`.