# How can I read keyboard input in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-input

I have problem with keyboard input in Python. I tried raw_input and it is called only once. But I want to read keyboard input every time user press any key. How can I do it? Thanks for answers.

Comment: Maybe a loop will help to read repeatedly from the keyboard

Comment: You can do this with `tkinter` but that may be overkill.  In what context are you trying to do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear... `raw_input` *does* read the keyboard input, any key press until the user hits "Enter". You should put some effort in describing what is it that you want to achieve.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175964/python-method-for-reading-keypress

Comment: I tried this http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Keyboard_input/Keypress_check#Python but it is not working. I typed to console is it wrong?

Comment: @alfasin I think what the OP is saying is quite clear.  He wants to read the input EVERY TIME the user presses a key.  raw_input only reads the input ONCE  -- after the user presses the Enter key.  It's true that raw_input reads all the input, but it only does it once.

Comment: @saulspatz and Vaclav, please check my answer edit.

Comment: @Václav Pavlíček When you say, "it is not working" that isn't very informative.  What is happening?  BTW, are you using Windows or some other OS?

Comment: Re-check my answer. Now it definitely works. I've just run it on my Mac.

Comment: I tried it on Mint and I want to print result to console. I tried breakpoint to return ch but it never stopped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So for instance you have a Python code like this:

#### file1.py

```
#!/bin/python
... do some stuff...
```

And at a certain point of the document you want to always check for input:

```
while True:
    input = raw_input(">>>")
    ... do something with the input...
```

That will always wait for input. You can thread that infinite loop as a separate process and do other things in the meanwhile, so that the user input can have an effect in the tasks you are doing.

If you instead want to ask for input ONLY when a key is pressed, and do that as a loop, with this code (taken from [this ActiveState recipe by Steven D'Aprano](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577977-get-single-keypress/)) you can wait for the key press to happen, and then ask for an input, execute a task and return back to the previous state.

> ```
> import sys
>
> try:
>     import tty, termios
> except ImportError:
>     # Probably Windows.
>     try:
>         import msvcrt
>     except ImportError:
>         # FIXME what to do on other platforms?
>         # Just give up here.
>         raise ImportError('getch not available')
>     else:
>         getch = msvcrt.getch
> else:
>     def getch():
>         """getch() -> key character
>
>         Read a single keypress from stdin and return the resulting character. 
>         Nothing is echoed to the console. This call will block if a keypress 
>         is not already available, but will not wait for Enter to be pressed. 
>
>         If the pressed key was a modifier key, nothing will be detected; if
>         it were a special function key, it may return the first character of
>         of an escape sequence, leaving additional characters in the buffer.
>         """
>         fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
>         old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
>         try:
>             tty.setraw(fd)
>             ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
>         finally:
>             termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
>         return ch
> ```

So how to deal with this? Well, now just call `getch()` every time you want to wait for a key press. Just like this:

```
while True:
    getch() # this also returns the key pressed, if you want to store it
    input = raw_input("Enter input")
    do_whatever_with_it
```

You can also thread that and do other tasks in the meanwhile.

Remember that Python 3.x does no longer use raw_input, but instead simply input().

Comment: @alfasin Python 3 is indeed relevant, because this is an open Q&A site, and more people than the OP visit the page. They must notice that buit-in method will only work in Py2.x. And the OP can know that too. Info does _not_ hurt.

Comment: There's a lot of interesting info which is not relevant to the question that you can add. About other programming languages too... Please keep the answer relevant to the question.

Comment: @J.C. Rocamonde  Please reformat the code in your answer, which looks excellent, BTW.

Comment: When i run it it throws this error: termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')

Comment: @VáclavPavlíček that's weird, its working for me. Just let me check it and solve your problem. Don't worry, we'll sort this out together.

Comment: @VáclavPavlíček exactly, which line does it tell you the error came from? Can you paste the full error message?

Comment: @VáclavPavlíček, you are not running the code from a terminal?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham how does that matter?

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde, unless where you are running the code is a tty then it is going to fail.

Comment: It throws error only in Pycharm but in command line it runs very well! Thank you for all!

Comment: @VáclavPavlíček just here to help! Do you want me to pass the loop to a thread? I can write an example for you

Comment: You should provide  a link to where you took the code from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577977-get-single-keypress/

Comment: @PadraicCunningham definitely. I'll do that now.

Answer (score 1):

In python2.x, simply use an infinite `while` loop with conditional `break`:

```
In [11]: while True:
    ...:     k = raw_input('> ')
    ...:     if k == 'q':
    ...:         break;
    ...:     #do-something


> test

> q

In [12]:
```

Comment: I don't think this does what the OP wants.  You have to press <Enter> after each key.  I think he wants to intercept individual key presses, like `getch` in C.  (If `getch` is the function I'm thinking of.)

Comment: @saulspatz Not sure, yet I may guess the OP doesn't know `getch` in C yet ;)

Comment: I don't think he knows it either, and since he's trying to write in python, it wouldn't do him any good if he did.  I'm not being critical of you, just trying to help out the OP. :-)