# Python key on press

Tags: python

I have an opening animation in my program that runs every time when the program is executed. It has about 5 frames, each frame is separated by a

```
from time import sleep
import os
print("frame 1")
sleep(2)
os.system('cls')
print("frame 2")
```

I already know that this is possible in a tk() window but is it possible in the console and during a sleep()? I am using python 3.5

i also see that others use

```
from msvcrt import getch
```

but for me it says that it does not exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python method for reading keypress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175964/python-method-for-reading-keypress)

Comment: yes I see but isn't   raw input  from python 2.7?   im using python 3.5 I will edit that in.