# Identifying a key press using python msvcrt

Tags: python, msvcrt

I want to use the `msvcrt` module in python, but I can't make it work.
I am on windows 10, have several "active keyboards" (I can change it from `azerty` to `qwerty` and stuff) and did not do/download anything except `Python3` itself (I'm saying that because maybe there are some requirements or manipulations to do that I don't know about).

What I'd like to do is simple -- press a key, and then do something according to the key that was pressed (so I need my computer to identify that key).

I tried it using the following code:

```
import msvcrt
while 1:                      #is that necessary?
    char = msvcrt.getch()
    if char == ???            #that's what I'm struggling with
        print("yay")
    else:
        print("nope")
```

I simply don't know how to "call" my key. I've tried for example `'\r'`, `char(13)`, ASCII codes and so on, but none of these worked. Chances are, they're supposed to but I'm doing it wrong- by not working I mean, I could never get a "yay", though the "right" key was pressed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python method for reading keypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175964/python-method-for-reading-keypress)

Comment: Of course one way to experiment is to print out the values that `getch()` returns when you press a specific key.

Answer (score 0):

You should prepend `b` before the wished key, i.e:

```
char = char = msvcrt.getch()
if char == b"\r":
    print("yay")
else:
    print("nope")
```

The [Python 3.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) states:

> Bytes literals are always prefixed with 'b' or 'B'; they produce an instance of the bytes type instead of the str type. They may only contain ASCII characters; bytes with a numeric value of 128 or greater must be expressed with escapes.

You can easily check it by yourself by looking at the output of `msvcrt.getch()` after you press the wished key.

```
>>> msvcrt.getch() # I pressed Enter
b'\r'
>>> msvcrt.getch() # I pressed SPACE
b' '
>>> msvcrt.getch() # I pressed BACKSPACE
b'\x08'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work with Python 3 on Windows 10:

```
import msvcrt
import os

os.system('cls')
while True:
    print('Press key [combination] (Kill console to quit): ', end='', flush=True)
    key = msvcrt.getwch()
    num = ord(key)
    if num in (0, 224):
        ext = msvcrt.getwch()
        print(f'prefix: {num}   -   key: {ext!r}   -   unicode: {ord(ext)}')
    else:
        print(f'key: {key!r}   -   unicode: {ord(key)}')
```

Comment: For me it issued this error: `
print(f'prefix: {num}   -   key: {ext!r}   -   unicode: {ord(ext)}')
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`