# Python: detect specific key press and prompt the user

Tags: python, keypress, prompt

I need to print out sentence "Hello World" every 10 seconds. However, if the user either 'c' or 'Enter', the program should stop printing the sentence and prompt the user to provide with the another sentence. The user-provided sentence is checked and if the sentence contains any digits, a message shows up: "cannot contain digits". Otherwise a message shows up: "correct sentence". After displaying either of the messages, the program continues printing "Hello World".

Here is the code I have strated with. Any hints on how to continue further would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

```
import threading

def looping():
    threading.Timer(10.0, looping).start()
    print("Hello World!")

looping()
```

Comment: What a weird assignment..... Anyway first try creating your program without the "Hello world" part every 10 seconds; just create a normal input-if-else structure. If that works, add the timer thing.  Be aware though that threads and console input/output don't work nicely together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of your assignment's instructions, it looks like you're on the right track with using a timer to print "Hello World"! I'd like to upvote Irmen de Jong's comment on your question with regard to the statement "threads and console input/output don't work nicely together", since I've experienced this myself in C programming.

Once you have the timer going, the text it prints to the screen shouldn't have an effect on responding to keyboard input. If it's really required to respond directly to a keypress of 'c' (not followed by 'Enter', as one would normally have to do when reading input from the keyboard with `input()`), I recommend following one of the solutions in [Python method for reading keypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175964/python-method-for-reading-keypress) to figure out how you would like to implement that.

EDIT: Implementing a solution using a thread-based timer is a bit more tricky than I thought.

As you may have found in your research on this problem, the `threading.Timer` object has both `start()` and `stop()` methods that you can use to control the execution of individual thread timers if you've saved a reference to the timer in a variable (e.g. doing `my_timer = threading.Timer(10.0, looping)` then calling `my_timer.start()` to start the timer). If you do this, you may be able to call `my_timer.stop()` to pause the looping, provided you've kept a proper reference to the current timer instance that you need to stop at that point in time.

To make things a bit easier, I chose to create a global variable `PAUSE_LOOPING` that, when set to `False`, will stop a new timer instance from being started when `looping` is called, thereby halting all further repetitions of the function until `PAUSE_LOOPING` is set back to `True` and `looping()` is called again:

```
import threading
from msvcrt import getch

PAUSE_LOOPING = False

def looping():
    global PAUSE_LOOPING
    if not PAUSE_LOOPING:
        threading.Timer(10.0, looping).start()
        print("Hello World!")

looping()

while True:
    # key = ord(getch())
    # if key == 13:  # Enter
    #     PAUSE_LOOPING = True
    input_string = input()
    if input_string == "":
        PAUSE_LOOPING = True
    else:
        PAUSE_LOOPING = False
        looping()
```

Commented out in the last code block is one way to grab a key press directly (without needing to press the 'Enter' key as is required by `input()`) taken from the stackoverflow question I linked to earlier in my answer. This should work as long as you're using Python for Windows (so you have the MS VC++ runtime library `msvcrt` installed), but to make the script stop when pressing 'Enter' you can use the standard `input()` function. In my example, typing any other string of characters before pressing 'Enter' will resume looping after it's been paused.

**NOTE: Beware of using Python's IDLE to run this code. It won't work. Instead, you must run it from the command line.**

Comment: For now, I am trying to figure out how I can make the current script stop when "Enter" button is pressed by the user. Most solutions I am coming across requires an input which is not there is my case.

Comment: Turns out the problem is a little tricky. I've updated my solution! Please accept my answer if it's what you were looking for. :)