# Listening for specific keys with pynput

Tags: python, pynput

I'd like my code to listen for user input, and do something if key `c` is pressed, and something else if key `v` is pressed.

I've managed to do it using `global`, but it feels like an ugly hack :

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        global user_input 
        if key.char == "c":
            user_input = "c"
        elif key.char == "v":
            user_input == "v"
    except AttributeError:
        pass

def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

def wait_for_user_input():
    global user_input
    listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
    listener.start()
    user_input = 0
    while user_input == 0:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if user_input == "c":
            # do something
            listener.stop()
            break
        elif user_input == "v":
            # do something else
            listener.stop()
            break
    # other stuff

wait_for_user_input()
```

Is there a better way to do it ? (Maybe by having the listener stop & return the values `c` or `v` in `on_press()` ? If so, I couldn't find how to do it.)

Also : since `wait_for_user_input()` will be called multiple times, would it be better to not start and stop the listener repetitively, and instead have it start once and stop once ?

Comment: do it directly inside `on_press`

Comment: Yeah but how ? Doing `return (False, "c")` doesn't work

Comment: why don't you run function directly in `on_press` - `if key.char == "c": your_function()`

Comment: I'll try it in a second, but I don't think it changes my problem : if I'm not mistaken, if I need what's returned by `your_function()` later, won't it have to go through a `global` variable ?

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work. Moreover, for some reason, it doesn't break out of the `while user_input == 0` loop.

Comment: when you put functions in `on_press` then you don't need `while loop`. You may only need `listener.join()` which will wait for `listener.stop()`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it. Can you explain in a proper answer, please ?

Answer (score 4):

You can put functions directly in `on_press` and then you don't need `while` loop. You may need only `listener.join()` which will wait for `listener.stop()`

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        if key.char == "c":
            # do something
            return False  # Stop listener
        elif key.char == "v":
            # do something else
            return False  # Stop listener
    except AttributeError as ex:
        print(ex)

def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

def wait_for_user_input():
    listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
    listener.start()
    listener.join() # wait till listener will stop
    # other stuff
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you need run functions which result you need in other functions then you may stay with `global user_input` but you can write it little different.

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    global user_input

    try:
        if key.char in ("c", "v"):
            user_input = key.char
            return False  # Stop listener
    except AttributeError as ex:
        print(ex)

def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False  # Stop listener

def wait_for_user_input():
    listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
    listener.start()
    listener.join() # wait till listener will stop

    if user_input == "c":
        # do something
    elif user_input == "v":
        # do something else
    else:
        print('You pressed ESC ?')
```

---

**EDIT:** If you use Windows then you could use `msvcrt.getch` which gives shorter and nicer code.

```
from msvcrt import getch

def wait_for_user_input():

    while True:
        user_input = getch()
        if user_input == "c":
            print('selected: c')
            break
        elif user_input == "v":
            print('selected: v')
            break
        elif user_input == escape:
            print('You pressed ESC ?')
            break

wait_for_user_input()
```

For Linux should be similar function `getch()` but with longer code.

See also module [getch](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) but I didn't check it.

Comment: Ok, but what if I need what's returned by stuff in the `# do something` part later in `wait_for_user_input()` ? (or even later, after another function has called `wait_for_user_input()`)

Comment: then you have to stay with your current code and don't bother of "ugly hack".

Comment: if you use Windows then you can use `msvcrt.getch()` in `while` loop and it will not look so ugly but very natural: [Python method for reading keypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175964/python-method-for-reading-keypress)

Comment: I created example with "ugly hack" but little nicer.