# How to print with getch() in one line?

Tags: python-3.x, getch

I have a problem in python3 .I want to print the "#" in only one line when I push "a" button in keyboard ,but with this code when I push for example 10 times the "a" ,doesn't appear the "#" ,but when I push the "q" button ,all "#" appears.
Why is this happening?
Also,in print function it shows me wrong the -> end=" "
Code:

```
import getch

while True:
    char = getch.getch()
    if(char == 'a'):
        print('#', end=" ")
    elif(char == "q"):
        break
```

Comment: see if this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175964/python-method-for-reading-keypress

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python method for reading keypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175964/python-method-for-reading-keypress)

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3, [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) can take an optional flush argument where the stream is forcibly flushed.

```
 print('#', sep=' ', end='', flush=True)
```