# Python Module for detecting Keyboard Strokes

Tags: python, keyboard

I wanted to make a program that detects if `w, a, s, and d` are continuously pressed, to detect if someone is gaming or not. Please let me know if anyone knows if this is possible or not.

Comment: Have you looked at pygame? Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it can detect keystrokes. https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python method for reading keypress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175964/python-method-for-reading-keypress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [keyboard library](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/)
And than to detect if one of the keys was pressed, use

```py
import keyboard
for key in "wasd":
    keyboard.add_hotkey(key, print, args=[key])

keyboard.wait()
```

This will print `w`, `a`, `s` or `d` if you press one of them.
The `keyboard.wait()` is there for the code to not stop running